# Opening a directory in c++

Tags: c++, stream, directory, move

I'm trying to write a program that moves files from one directory to another, so far I have this written.

```
void file_Move(ifstream in,ofstream out)
{
    string name, name2; 
    int downloads;

    cout << "Enter 1 if the file you wish to move is in downloads" << endl;
    cin >> downloads;

        if (downloads == 1)
        {
            opendir("F:/Downloads"); //supposed to open the directory so that the user can input the file they wish to be moved.
            closedir("F:/Downloads");
        }
}
```

Visual Studio doesn't have the dirent.h library which is necessary for opendir and closedir, so I was wondering if there was a similar or better way of doing what those do.

Comment: Dealing with directories requires OS-specific functions, it's not part of the C++ specification.

Comment: If you are asking about the Win32 API, then look up FindFirstFile and FindNextFile and associated function on MSDN.

Comment: [`std::rename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename) or [`std::filesystem::rename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/rename)?

Comment: @Barmar: Actually, it *is* part of the soon to be officially current specification to which the committee just recently gave its approval.

Comment: _Actually, it is part of the soon to be officially current specification_ ...finally, can't believe it took them so long. If you can't wait until C++17 there is still [boost::filesystem::rename](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#rename).

Comment: @zett42 We're talking about something analogous to `opendir/readdir/closedir` to get all the filenames in a directory, not the function for renaming the files once they're found.

Comment: @Barmar you can do this with [std::filesystem::directory_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) or [boost::filesystem::directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator).

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make much sense as it stands right now.

On one hand, `file_move` takes an ifstream and an ofstream, which would imply that you've already found and opened the files you care about. Then it goes on to attempt to search for files...

For the moment, I'm going to assume you need to search for the files you care about. In this case, you probably want to use the `filesystem` library. With a really up to date compiler, this may be directly in `std::`. For a slightly older compiler, it may be in `std::experimental`. For one that's older still (predates the Filesystem TS) you'll probably need to use [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) instead.

In any case, code to use this would run something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

void show_files(std::string const & path) {
    // change to the std or Boost variant as needed.
    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem::v1;

    fs::path p{ path };

    fs::directory_iterator b{ p }, e;

    std::transform(b, e, 
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"), 
        [](fs::path const &p) {
            return p.string();
        }
    );
}
```

Of course, if you're going to copy files, you probably want to put the file names in a vector (or something on that order) rather than just displaying them--but presumably you know how to do what you want once you have file names to work with.

In any case, to call this you can just pass the path to the directory you care about, such as `F:/Downloads`:

```
show_files("f:/Downloads");
```

Of course, under a system that uses POSIX paths, you'll pass a different input string (e.g., might be something like `"/home/some_user/Downloads"` instead). Oh, and at least with its usual directory structure, with g++ the header will be `experimental/filesystem` instead of just `filesystem`.